# CertificateNotfound error when creating LB Listener

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I am having trouble adding a certificate to my LB listener. Here is the code used to do so (note these is a snippets of code):

#### global/main.tf

```
  resource "aws_acm_certificate" "demo_cert_east" {
  provider          = "aws.east"
  domain_name       = "*.mydomain.com"
  validation_method = "DNS"

  tags {
    Name        = "demo certificate"
    Environment = "demo"
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

#### stage/main.tf

```
data "aws_acm_certificate" "demo_cert" {
  domain   = "*.mydomain.com"
  statuses = ["ISSUED", "PENDING_VALIDATION"]
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "wfe_demo_ssl" {
  load_balancer_arn = "${aws_lb.wfe_demo.arn}"
  port              = "443"
  protocol          = "HTTPS"
  ssl_policy        = "ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08"
  certificate_arn   = "${data.aws_acm_certificate.demo_cert.arn}"

  default_action {
    target_group_arn = "${aws_lb_target_group.wfe_demo.arn}"
    type             = "forward"
  }
}
```

I have ensured that both resources are in the aws-east region. I am getting the error:

> Error creating LB Listener: CertificateNotFound: Certificate 'arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:078395932517:certificate/b83ba534-ef9d-4a07-ae13-832695dc8b5a' not found.

So the certificate is getting retrieved correctly by the data source but the listener then can't seem to find it.

Comment: Why are you using the data source as well as the resource to actually create it? I'm also confused why you have the `provider = "aws.east"` line on the `aws_acm_certificate` if you're using US East 1 for everything here?

Comment: sorry i should have clarified, this is a snippet of my code and this is the relevant information. I defined the resource in one file so I can maintain it. Then in a different directory I access the created certificate

Comment: Has the certificate been validated? You can't attach a non `ISSUED` certificate to a load balancer. You should probably drop the `PENDING_VALIDATION` status from the data source.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR The problem was the certificate wasn't issued at the point of trying, hope this helps someone else

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To be able to attach an ACM certificate to a load balancer or other AWS resource such as Cloudfront, it must have been validated first.

Changing your data source to find only `ISSUED` certificates should then push the error to happen in the data source if there are no validated certificates that match your pattern:

```
data "aws_acm_certificate" "demo_cert" {
  domain   = "*.mydomain.com"
  statuses = ["ISSUED"]
}
```

To validate the certificate you can either handle this out of band manually when you request it, use some other tool to automatically validate it for you or you can use Terraform's [`aws_acm_certificate_validation` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/acm_certificate_validation.html) when creating the ACM certificate request:

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "cert" {
  domain_name = "example.com"
  validation_method = "DNS"
}

data "aws_route53_zone" "zone" {
  name = "example.com."
  private_zone = false
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "cert_validation" {
  name = aws_acm_certificate.cert.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_name
  type = aws_acm_certificate.cert.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_type
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.zone.id
  records = [aws_acm_certificate.cert.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_value]
  ttl = 60
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "cert" {
  certificate_arn = aws_acm_certificate.cert.arn
  validation_record_fqdns = [aws_route53_record.cert_validation.fqdn]
}
```

Comment: Issue was the certificate was still pending and thus couldn't be used. Hope this helps someone

Comment: @SamMallabone how long did it take for your certificate to be validated? I've been waiting for a full day now

Comment: @sokras this seems like it might be worth a separate question. If you could show the process you are using to validate the ACM request that would be useful.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I am using DNS validation, I have added the required records to our dns db and i've been waiting since yesterday for the validation to be completed. We own the root domain under which I have created the domain I need e.g. newdomain.rootdomain.com

Comment: @ydaetskcoR It was an error on my end, I forgot to set the `domain_id` field for the records I needed to add to my dns db. I'm using pdns 4.1.x

Answer (score 5):

Because I just had the issue: certificate and resource must be in the same region. (@ydaetskcoR kind of mentioned this already).